# How does firebase identifies player's location?

Tags: firebase, app-store, firebase-analytics

On firebase the country wise data is collected by the tracking of device locality (language) or by the country wise app store ?
For example, I am in Mexico and I switched my iPhone app store location to US, downloaded the game from US App store.

So, Which country will firebase label me ? Mexico or US ?
Because as per App Store data, I'll be considering in US traffic and my ratings and reviews also will be counting in US store.

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [How Geographical Data import works](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6160484):

> Analytics provides a number of geographical dimensions, such as City, Country, Continent, etc. The values for **these dimensions are automatically derived from the IP address of the hit**

See the link for full details.

Note: for this purpose there is no difference between "Google Analytics" and "Google Analytics for Firebase" as the location is determined in the same way, no matter how the event reaches Google Analytics' servers.

Comment: For example, if I change my location to US, then my IP will also be changed to US? Does it mean that google Analytics will identify me as US user ?